# Problems installing package plotly in R

Tags: r, installation, plotly

I need to install the pakage plotly for a curent project, but when I try to do it, the following is reported:

```
#install.packages("plotly")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/.../R/win-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
       binary source needs_compilation
plotly 4.10.1 4.10.2             FALSE

installing the source package ‘plotly’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/plotly_4.10.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3902837 bytes (3.7 MB)
downloaded 3.7 MB

* installing *source* package 'plotly' ...
** package 'plotly' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** demo
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Warning message:
package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.1.3 
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'cli' 3.3.0 is already loaded, but >= 3.4.0 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace
Execução interrompida
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'plotly'
* removing 'C:/Users/.../R/win-library/4.1/plotly'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘plotly’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\...\Temp\Rtmp88i3OR\downloaded_packages’
```

I tried different resolutions, but none of it seemed to work. Does anyone know what I can do to solve this problem and install the package properly?

I tried to reinstall Rstudio, but it haven't solved.

I tried to dowload through github, but it also didn't worked.

Anyway, I don't know what else to do, but I'll be happy if anyone have an idea on how to solve it

Comment: If you look at your initial error, you need `rtools`. Did you do that? This is something that is specific to Windows OS; when you install R (base R), you also need to download Rtools from the [R website](https://cran.r-project.org/). After that's installed, if you still have problems, edit your question.

Comment: It looks like this is caused by the error "namespace 'cli' 3.3.0 is already loaded, but >= 3.4.0 is required". Restart R so no packages are loaded, then run `install.packages("cli")` first to update that package. Make sure that runs without error before trying to install plotly.